# VirtualBox4.2 kills lightdm

Tags: virtualbox, 13.04, lightdm

I just installed VirtualBox4.2 on Ubuntu 13.04. When I open VirtualBox, all seems well, until I try to create an new VM, at which point, lightdm crashes, and I am forced (eventually) back to the login screen.

is anyone running VirtaulBox in Ubuntu 13.04 and having the same issue?
Does anyone know a fix to this?

here is what looks like relivent `dmesg` info

```
[   19.575962] vboxdrv: Found 2 processor cores.
[   19.578171] vboxdrv: fAsync=1 offMin=0x13c76d offMax=0x13c76d
[   19.580595] vboxdrv: TSC mode is 'asynchronous', kernel timer mode is 'normal'.
[   19.580603] vboxdrv: Successfully loaded version 4.2.12 (interface 0x001a0004).
[   19.957340] vboxpci: IOMMU not found (not registered)
[   22.450277] init: plymouth-upstart-bridge main process (1020) killed by TERM signal
[   22.864046] de2104x 0000:01:06.0 eth0: link up, media 10baseT-HD
[   22.864074] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
[   25.435531] audit_printk_skb: 78 callbacks suppresse
[   25.435543] type=1400 audit(1367507475.203:38): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" parent=1366 profile="/sbin/dhclient" name="/var/lib/NetworkManager/dhclient6-eth0.conf" pid=1824 comm="dhclient" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0
[  261.756237] warning: `VirtualBox' uses 32-bit capabilities (legacy support in use)
```

Comment: I am having a tough time with this forums formatting options.

Comment: Please use this post to familiarize yourself with formatting http://askubuntu.com/editing-help

Comment: I installed the VirtualBox4.2 from Oracles download site. So then i uni stalled it, and tried the version in the software centre. The same problem persists.

Comment: Did you get a chance to look at my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the following file

`sudo vim /etc/apparmor.d/sbin.dhclient`

look for the following entry in that file

`/var/lib/NetworkManager/dhclient-*.conf lrw,`

replace it with this line

`/var/lib/NetworkManager/dhclient*.conf lrw,`

and then reboot

`reboot`

Comment: How is this related? It doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: I saw this line 

`[   25.435543] type=1400 audit(1367507475.203:38): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" parent=1366 profile="/sbin/dhclient" name="/var/lib/NetworkManager/dhclient6-eth0.conf" pid=1824 comm="dhclient" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0`